An affine trasformation as a composition of affine trasformations and their geometric implications
Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix such that $\det (A) \ne 0$ and we consider the affine trasformation $T\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ defined as $$x\mapsto Ax+b,\tag1$$ where $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Can I write $T$ as a composition of three affine trasformation?

For example for $n=1$ we have for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ that $$x\mapsto  ax+b$$ and the $$T=T_3T_2T_1,$$ where $$T_1x:=\frac{a}{|a|}x,\quad T_2x:=|a|x,\quad T_3x:= x+b$$
Then in the case $n=1$ we can write an affine trasformation as a composition of trasformation whose geometric implications are clear.
I ask if something similar is possible for the generic case. And therefore if we can write an affine transformation of the type $(1)$ as compositions of transformations whose geometric implications are clear and similar to those of the $n=1$ case.

$T=T\circ id\circ id$

But it's already affine.  So $T = T \circ \mathrm{id} \circ \mathrm{id}$? This can't be what you meant.

You should add some constraints I guess

@AnneBauvalNo, I would like something that involves the linear transformation $Ax$ in some way.

Please edit your post to specify clearly your additional constraint(s).

You mean one rotation, one homotety and one translation? It is not the case in higher dimension but you can have one orthogonal, one symmetric definite positive and one translation

Sorry if I was unclear, I've corrected the post now.

Is my comment an answer to you?

@julio_es_sui_glaceI don't know how to translate what you suggested in mathematical terms, could you be more detailed? Thank you.

Again: Please edit your post to specify clearly your additional constraint(s) ("something similar to what was just said in the case $n=1$" is not clear), and include some "context": Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

As I just sad you need to change it a little in higher dimension, but you can generalise this decomposition.
Suppose you have $T(x) = Ax+b$ with $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\det A \neq 0$.
There is something called polar decomposition (you can find several proof online) which states that for any square matrix $A$ there exists an unique couple $(O,S)$ with $O \in O_n(\mathbb R)$ and $S \in S_n^{++} (\mathbb R )$ satisfying $A = SO$. This is the correct generalisation of respectively $a/|a|$ and $|a|$.
Now This gives you
$$T(x) = t_b\left(S(O(x))\right) = t_b \circ S \circ O (x) $$
Beware, $O$ could be a reflexion and is not necessarily a bunch of rotations! It is just an isometry (preserves distance and angles) $S$ does all the scaling necessary.
If $\det A = 0$ you still have a decomposition but it is not unique.
